# ffmpeg, lower fps with gpu - too many packets buffered

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to lower the fps for a large set of videos. Unfortunately, I don't have much experience with ffmpeg

This is my current command, which is a hybrid of multiple posts. At this point it's more guess work than anything else

```
ffmpeg \
  -y -hwaccel_output_format cuda -hwaccel_device 0 -hwaccel cuvid -c:v mpeg2_cuvid \
  -i myinput.mp4 -r 25 -c:v hevc_nvenc-b:v 128K -strict -2 -movflags faststart \ 
  /workspace/videos/24fps_trial2/rat1-control2.mp4 -c:v hevc_nvenc
```

The gist of it is just that I'm trying to lower fps and use hardware acceleration since my dataset is large

The message I get is

```
Trailing option(s) found in the command: may be ignored.
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x453a100] decoding for stream 0 failed
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x453a100] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: mpeg2video (hvc1 / 0x31637668), none(tv), 2704x1520, 59946 kb/s): unspecified pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/workspace/gs/Rat Controls Jan 2020 /Rat 1 Control 2 .MP4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp41
    minor_version   : 538120216
    compatible_brands: mp41
    creation_time   : 2020-01-07T09:45:34.000000Z
    firmware        : HD7.01.01.70.00
  Duration: 00:01:49.63, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 60202 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mpeg2video (hvc1 / 0x31637668), none(tv), 2704x1520, 59946 kb/s, 119.88 fps, 119.88 tbr, 120k tbn, 120k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-01-07T09:45:34.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro H.265
      encoder         : GoPro H.265 encoder
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 189 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-01-07T09:45:34.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro AAC
    Stream #0:2(eng): Data: bin_data (gpmd / 0x646D7067), 29 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-01-07T09:45:34.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro MET
    Stream #0:3(eng): Data: none (fdsc / 0x63736466), 21 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-01-07T09:45:34.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro SOS
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mpeg2video (mpeg2_cuvid) -> hevc (hevc_nvenc))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Too many packets buffered for output stream 0:1.
[aac @ 0x45bf880] Qavg: 746.362
[aac @ 0x45bf880] 2 frames left in the queue on closing
Conversion failed!
```

Comment: Why `-c:v mpeg2_cuvid`? MP4s typically contain H.264 and so will require `-c:v h264_cuvid`

Comment: I get ```cuvid decode callback error
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Generic error in an external library
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input```. I think they're h265, but somehow mpeg doesn't have the error when h264 does

Comment: I now see the tag, so it should be `hevc_cuvid`.

Comment: you are a hero. The 2h runtime just went down to less than a minute. How did you know that? Was it from this line:  `Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mpeg2video (mpeg2_cuvid) -> hevc (hevc_nvenc))`

Comment: No, from this: `Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mpeg2video (hvc1 / 0x31637668)` - hvc1 is a tag for HEVC.